# rapid location.replace causes browser crash

Tags: jquery, url

I'm using jQuery [maximage](http://www.aaronvanderzwan.com/maximage/) which has jQuery [Cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) at its core, to navigate through slides, and amend (replace) the location hash on each transition.

It works, except if you try and navigate too quickly; at which point the browser (tested in Firefox and Chrome) will crash, as the page tries endlessly to reload itself.

```
$(function(){
    var h, 
        hash = window.location.hash, 
        hashes = {},
        index = 0;
    // Iterate slides into hashes object
    $('#slides').children('div').each(function(i) {
        h = $(this).attr('id');
        // Change IDs to hash format
        h = h.replace(/\ /g, '-');
        hashes[h] = i;
        slideInteger = i
    });
    if (hash) {
        index = hashes[hash.substring(1)] || index;
    };
    $('#slides').maximage({
        cycleOptions: {
            startingSlide: index,
            cssTransitions: true,
            after: onAfter,
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 360,
            timeout: 0
        },
        onFirstImageLoaded: function(){
            $('#cycle-loader').hide();
            // Remove tooltip on hover
            $('.mc-image').hover(function(){
                $(this).removeAttr('title');
            });
        }
    });
    function onAfter(el, next_el, opts) {
        var nextHash = $(next_el).find('.slideLink').text().toLowerCase().replace(/\ /g, '-');
        window.location.replace(('' + window.location).split('#')[0] + '#' + nextHash);
    };
    $(window).on("hashchange", function() {
        $('#slides').cycle(hashes[window.location.hash.substring(1)] || 0);
    });
});
```

I tried replacing the onAfter function with...

```
function onAfter(el, next_el, opts) {
    var nextHash = $(next_el).find('.slideLink').text().toLowerCase().replace(/\ /g, '-');
    if( window.location.hash != ('#' + nextHash) ){
        window.location.replace(('' + window.location).split('#')[0] + '#' + nextHash);
    }
};
```

...but it didn't seem to make any difference.

This doesn't seem to something I can duplicate in jsfiddle either - so apologies for the lack of physical demonstration.

Comment: Be careful reading `window.location.hash`. Historically, some browsers return a string with the leading `#` and some without (IIRC, the standard says it should be without). Although all the major browsers may now conform, it's still prudent to allow for `window.location.hash` to return either version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the HTML5 `history.pushState`/`history.replaceState` API for that. You also have shims for older browsers.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history
"Adding and modifying history entries"

Comment: I'm guessing you mean history.replaceState - as I'm not looking to add any other history entries. But this works, thanks. Now the problem of supporting older browsers...